# Python - UnboundLocalError: local variable "ID" referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
def hour(cn):
   for z in range(9,17):  
      if now.hour == z:
         worksheet(cn, str(z)+":00")

def identify(number):
   sht = gc.open("Test")
   wks3 = sht.worksheet("NAMES")
   b = wks3.acell('B'+str(number)).value
   a = wks3.acell('A'+str(number)).value
   if(Id == a and conf<65):
     print(Id, conf)
     Id = str(b)
     Time = time.ctime()
     hour(number)
   elif(conf>64):
     print(conf)
     Id = "Unknown"

for m in range(2,100):

     identify(m)
```

The above code is being used for facial recognition, I copied what I felt was necessary, **it is not the entire code.**

I'm trying create a function which I want to call back in a for loop

What am I doing wrong? I've been looking t this for 6 hours now, and anything I try doesn't seem to work.

I get a message back saying "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Id' referenced before assignment"

It's impossible because I'm assigning with:

```
a = wks3.acell('A'+str(number)).value
```

So it grabs the ID number from the google spread sheet and checks if it is equaled to that, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: How is the computer supposed to evaluate `Id == a` when `Id` doesn't have a value at that point?

Comment: You need to actually set the value of Id before you can use it.

Comment: Why would you think that setting the value of `a` would solve the problem with `Id` being undefined?

Comment: It is set, read again "not the entire code"

Comment: Why downvote also? doesn't help at all

Comment: So why aren't you showing us the code where it is set, since that is the whole issue?

Comment: I'll show it now Mr Roseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def identify(number):
   sht = gc.open("Test")
   wks3 = sht.worksheet("NAMES")
   b = wks3.acell('B'+str(number)).value
   a = wks3.acell('A'+str(number)).value
   #because you did, Id = ? 
   if(Id == a and conf<65):
     print(Id, conf)
     Id = str(b)
     Time = time.ctime()
     hour(number)
   elif(conf>64):
     print(conf)
     Id = "Unknown"
```

Because you did, variable Id isn't passed as any parameter or global/local variable or as an argument to existing class.

If **Id** was parameter:

```
def identify(number,Id):
```

If **Id** was global variable:

```
def identify(number):
    global Id
```

If **Id** was local variable:

```
def identify(number):
    id = None # or some other data type
```

And if **Id** was argument from some class:

```
some_class.Id
```

In short you referenced Id before it was initialised. This is rookie mistake and there is some stuff where you can actually init a variable in *if elif else* statement but you need to trow a none of above logic of the rule.

```
if True: Id = 2; elif False: Id = 3; else: Id =0 #this is pseudocode, don't paste it in.
```

Also have in mind that next variable is also Unbound **`conf`**

---

EDIT:

Often to avoid this problem we write code like this:

```
def somefunction(parm1,parm2... ): 

    # global variables : description for variable stack is optional
    global var1,var2 # if needed  

    #local variables  
    var3,var4 = None;  
    var5 = 'something else'  

    #in body functions : functions inside functions or just general program functions 
    def a(... ): return ...  

    #body : actually what function/program does.   

    # returning , finishing statement.
```

Comment: Appreciated, minus the condescension though.

Comment: No problem, although condescension is warranted. I can understand that you are new to stackoverflow or to python. And i know that python can be tricky for beginners to grasp ( all those classes, types and etc ) but this code doesn't have etiquette, and this coding style is prone to phantom errors. You should init variables first, functions and lambdas second and then body of code so when someone wants to read your code they don't need to find the start in Wonderland.